# Can an unprivileged user on Windows DNS poison itself?

Tags: windows, dns

Can an unprivileged user on a Windows machine spoof DNS responses the machine it is running on makes? For example, if a privileged command prompt ran `nslookup example.com`, can an unprivileged process intercept the request or affect the reply?

Comment: To do what you ask, a Windows process would need to control the networking stack. That requires admin privileges.

Comment: Unless there's a specific exploit that can cause it, no.

Comment: Right, I was thinking on the lines of GetUdpTable. GetUdpTable returns all active connections, so if you spammed in a significant amount and the second the udp connection is made you should be able to see the dns packet and then respond quickly?

Comment: It sounds possible to use that technique to see when a DNS request is made, but you're not going to be able to produce a valid reply without seeing the contents of the packet, for which you would need a packet sniffer installed.